# Staff users don't have permission to access admin site without explicitly assigning them

Tags: python, django, windows, permission-denied

I'm using Django 3.1.2 and staff users added by superuser in the admin site can't access the same admin site after login. All pages in /admin/ return 403 forbidden error.

I'm using Windows 10, Python 3.8.5, inside a virtual environment (venv). My commands were made in Git Bash. It first happened in other project, so i created a new one to try. It's the same error in Firefox, Edge and Chrome.

Exactly what i did:

**Git Bash:**

```
$ mkdir test_staff
$ cd test_staff/
$ python -m venv venv_dev
$ source venv_dev/Scripts/activate
$ pip install Django==3.1.2
$ pip list
    Package    Version
    ---------- -------
    asgiref    3.2.10
    Django     3.1.2
    pip        20.1.1
    pytz       2020.1
    setuptools 47.1.0
    sqlparse   0.4.1
$ django-admin startproject mysite
$ cd mysite/
$ python manage.py migrate
$ winpty python manage.py createsuperuser
    username: admin
    password: 12345
$ python manage.py runserver
```

**Browser:**

```
Login with "admin" user: ​http://localhost:8000/admin/login
Add staff user: ​http://localhost:8000/admin/auth/user/add/
    username: staff_user
    password: Ax47y](U[1fpw;8H2?})
    > Save and continue editing
    staff status = True
    > Save 
Logout: ​http://localhost:8000/admin/logout/
Login with "staff_user": ​http://localhost:8000/admin/login
```

**Result:**
[image]

**Git Bash:**

```
[09/Oct/2020 12:49:39] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2282
```

**Other URL:**
[image]

**Git Bash:**

```
Forbidden (Permission denied): /admin/auth/user/
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\DELL\Documents\github\test_staff\venv_dev\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
File "C:\Users\DELL\Documents\github\test_staff\venv_dev\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\DELL\Documents\github\test_staff\venv_dev\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 614, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\DELL\Documents\github\test_staff\venv_dev\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\DELL\Documents\github\test_staff\venv_dev\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\DELL\Documents\github\test_staff\venv_dev\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 233, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\DELL\Documents\github\test_staff\venv_dev\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\DELL\Documents\github\test_staff\venv_dev\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\DELL\Documents\github\test_staff\venv_dev\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1690, in changelist_view
    raise PermissionDenied
django.core.exceptions.PermissionDenied
[09/Oct/2020 12:53:50] "GET /admin/auth/user/ HTTP/1.1" 403 135
```

**Staff users can only access admin site if i explicitly assign auth permissions to the user.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how it should be. Your new staff users don't have any permissions to add or edit anything. Try creating a new Group with a set of permissions (such as adding/editing Users or other models), then add your staff users to that Group.